# What is the For-Case Antipattern?

Tags: anti-patterns

[Today's TDWTF article](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/a-foursome-of-arrays) starts with a confession from the author:

> I didn’t know what the For-Case anti-pattern was until relatively recently, when there were a spate of articles condemning it as an anti-pattern. I’m sure I’ve probably *used* it, at some point, but I never knew it by *name*. It’s thought of as a textbook antipattern that generally implies a misunderstanding of for loop, case statements, the problem being solved, or some combination of all three.

He then proceeds as if the reader, naturally, knows what the For-Case anti-pattern is without any further explanation being needed.

But I don't! I haven't seen the "spate of articles" that Remy talks about, and the only significant reference that I can find on Google (besides Remy's article) is a [blog post by Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793) about the *for-if* antipattern, which is apparently related. He doesn't define the "for-case anti-pattern" either, though.

What is this "For-Case anti-pattern" that these guys are talking about, and what makes it an anti-pattern?

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_FOR-CASE_paradigm

Comment: It's commonly known as (and easier to find via search engines) as the [*loop-switch anti-pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The "pattern" was introduced in [an earlier Daily WTF article.](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_FOR-CASE_paradigm)  The basic idea is that you have a `for` loop with a `case` inside of it that selects based on the `for` loop index variable.

Assuming the index variable can't be changed inside the loop, (which is not always true, depending on which language you're using,) a bit of analysis demonstrates that the execution is exactly the same as if you removed the `for` and the `case` entirely and all the case blocks were simply executed sequentially.

Answer (score -1):

To put it very simply, you're nesting two different flow control methods, which makes the code harder to understand.

If you see a for loop, you generally assume that loop conditions will control the logic within the loop. But if you then nest a whole case statement inside, with all of its own logic, that goes out the window.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with nesting two control flow structures. Sometimes you need to. But in this case it's useless.

Comment: *"which makes the code harder to understand."* Boy, is that ever the understatement of the day/month/year.

Comment: This is *not* why the for-case antipattern is stupid.